# Does SCSS supports arrays in variables?

Tags: sass

I have a @mixin for paragraphs that looks like this:

```
@mixin paragraph {
    color: $dark-700;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to create a $paragraph variable with all those styles in an array or object to call it every time.

Comment: I'm not sure, But I think you will need to pass your values as parameters. that's just it

Comment: Create a map with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but maybe placeholder selectors are what you are looking for:

```scss
%paragraph {
   color: $dark-700;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 20px;
}

.section-description {
  @extend %paragraph;
}

.banner-text {
  @extend %paragraph;
}
```

More info: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors